# Tag consecutive non zero rows into distinct partitions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

Suppose we have this simple schema and data:

```
DROP TABLE #builds
CREATE TABLE #builds (
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    StartTime INT,
    IsPassed BIT
)
INSERT INTO #builds (StartTime, IsPassed) VALUES
(1, 1),
(7, 1),
(10, 0),
(15, 1),
(21, 1),
(26, 0),
(34, 0),
(44, 0),
(51, 1),
(60, 1)

SELECT StartTime, IsPassed, NextStartTime,
    CASE IsPassed WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE NextStartTime - StartTime END Duration
FROM (
    SELECT  
        LEAD(StartTime) OVER (ORDER BY StartTime) NextStartTime,
        StartTime, IsPassed
    FROM #builds
) x
ORDER BY StartTime
```

It produces the following result set:

```
StartTime   IsPassed    NextStartTime   Duration
1           1           7               0
7           1           10              0
10          0           15              5
15          1           21              0
21          1           26              0
26          0           34              8
34          0           44              10
44          0           51              7
51          1           60              0
60          1           NULL            0
```

I need to summarize the non zero consecutive Duration values and to show them at the StartTime of the first row in the batch. I.e. I need to get to this:

```
StartTime   Duration
10          5
26          25
```

I just can't figure out how to do it.

PS: The real table contains many more rows, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem, requiring partitioning each section where `IsPassed` is constant into a different group. That can be done by computing the difference between `ROW_NUMBER()` over the entire table against partitioned by `IsPassed`. You can then `SUM` the `Duration` Values for each group where `IsPassed = False` and take the `MIN(StartTime)` to give the `StartTime` of the first row of the group:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT StartTime, IsPassed,
         LEAD(StartTime) OVER (ORDER BY StartTime) AS NextStartTime
  FROM #builds
),
CTE2 AS (
  SELECT StartTime, IsPassed, NextStartTime,
         CASE IsPassed WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE NextStartTime - StartTime END Duration,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartTime) -
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IsPassed ORDER BY StartTime) AS grp
  FROM CTE
)
SELECT MIN(StartTime) AS StartTime, SUM(Duration) AS Duration
FROM CTE2
WHERE IsPassed = 0
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY MIN(StartTime)
```

Output:

```
StartTime   Duration
10          5
26          25
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e69b4a4387e0c8f5998360e4a84b650a)

Comment: This is absolutely gorgeous. I managed to understand that my problem is a kind of gaps and islands (I learned about the term in the past couple of hours), but I failed to understand the theory and figure out how do I group. This is great.

Comment: @mark it took me forever to get my head around it. I left the `SELECT * FROM CTE2` query in the demo so you could see the group numbers being formed. Once you have them getting the result isn't too hard.

Comment: @mark I just noticed I left in an unnecessary `LAG` of `IsPassed` in the first CTE. I've updated the answer and demo to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is unnecessarily complicated.  You simply need to assign the `0`s to groups that include exactly the following `1`.

You can do this by counting the number of "1"s on or after each row.  Of course, this also assigns a grouping to the rows with no "0"s.  These can be filtered out by ensuring that there is at least on `0` in each group:

```
select min(StartTime), max(startTime) - min(startTime)
from (select b.*,
             sum(case when IsPassed = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by StartTime desc) as grp
      from builds b
     ) b
group by grp
having min(convert(int, IsPassed)) = 0
order by min(StartTime);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f0d5f98a242b38670ffbc04911906be6) is a db<>fiddle.

Or an alternative method uses no aggregation at all.  It simply gets the next "1" starttime for each row and then filters down to the first "0" row:

```
select StartTime, next_1_starttime - StartTime
from (select b.*,
             lag(IsPassed) over (order by StartTime) as prev_IsPassed,
             min(case when IsPassed = 1 then StartTime end) over (order by StartTime desc) as next_1_starttime
      from builds b
     ) b
where IsPassed = 0 and (prev_IsPassed = 1 or prev_IsPassed is null)
order by StartTime;
```

This probably has the best performance of the alternatives.

Comment: So they key is to group the rows and I failed to find a way. I do not understand in the first variant how `sum(case when IsPassed = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by StartTime desc)` works. There is no partitioning, so what does `sum` do exactly? I will look at the second variant shortly.

Comment: Your answer highlights the sorrow truth - I do not understand how window functions work. In the second variant you use min without partitioning again - how does it work?

Comment: @mark . . . If there is no `partition by`, then all the rows are in one partition.  I think the answer explains how these work -- they are using window functions to assign an appropriate grouping to the data.  This is much simpler (and probably faster) than your approach or the approach in the other answer.