# Tag consecutive non zero rows into distinct partitions, this time using kusto - the query language of the Azure AppInsights

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

We are using Azure DevOps Server 2019 (on-prem). As such, the build analytics are pretty non existing. So, we have setup a process to upload the finished build metrics to Azure AppInsights, which allows us to write all kinds of interesting dashboards.

My manager wants to know three things:

1. How often does the build fail?
2. How long do the builds take?
3. How long does the build stay broken?

The first two are pretty straightforward, but the last one is pretty hard.

First, I translated the problem into Sql and solved it with the help of [Tag consecutive non zero rows into distinct partitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59889916/tag-consecutive-non-zero-rows-into-distinct-partitions/59890094?noredirect=1#comment105908722_59890094)

Having received the answer for the Sql, I was able to translate it to the Kql (Kusto Query Language used by AppInsights) like this:

```
customEvents
| where customDimensions.kind == "build"
    and name == 'vNext_master_ci_r_git'
| project
    startTime = todatetime(customDimensions.startTime),
    outcome = tostring(customDimensions.buildResult)
| where outcome in ('succeeded', 'failed')
| order by startTime asc
| extend 
    nextStartTime = next(startTime, 1)
| extend 
    duration = case(outcome == 'failed', nextStartTime - startTime, totimespan(0)),
    rn = row_number(),
    rn2 = row_number(1, prev(outcome) != outcome)
| extend 
    grp = rn - rn2
| where outcome == 'failed'
| summarize startTime = min(startTime), duration = toreal(sum(duration) / time(1h)) by grp
| order by startTime asc
| project startTime, duration
```

As you can see, this is a 1-1 translation of the respective Sql. But, I wonder if there is a more concise way to achieve this goal in Kql. My rationale is that Kql was designed to support data analysis and so maybe it can provide more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that the following is what you look for, but it is definitely more concise. In addition, I don't have a sample of the data, so I tried to construct part of it from your query. So let's assume we have:

```
let customEvents = datatable (customDimensions: dynamic, name: string)
[
  dynamic({ "kind": "build", "startTime": "2021-01-14T10:00:00Z", "buildResult": "succeeded" }), "vNext_master_ci_r_git", 
  dynamic({ "kind": "build", "startTime": "2021-01-14T11:00:00Z", "buildResult": "failed" }), "vNext_master_ci_r_git", 
  dynamic({ "kind": "build", "startTime": "2021-01-14T12:00:00Z", "buildResult": "failed" }), "vNext_master_ci_r_git",
  dynamic({ "kind": "build", "startTime": "2021-01-14T13:00:00Z", "buildResult": "failed" }), "vNext_master_ci_r_git",
  dynamic({ "kind": "build", "startTime": "2021-01-14T14:00:00Z", "buildResult": "succeeded" }), "vNext_master_ci_r_git",
  dynamic({ "kind": "build", "startTime": "2021-01-14T15:00:00Z", "buildResult": "succeeded" }), "vNext_master_ci_r_git",
  dynamic({ "kind": "build", "startTime": "2021-01-14T16:00:00Z", "buildResult": "succeeded" }), "vNext_master_ci_r_git",
  dynamic({ "kind": "build", "startTime": "2021-01-14T17:00:00Z", "buildResult": "failed" }), "vNext_master_ci_r_git",
  dynamic({ "kind": "build", "startTime": "2021-01-14T18:00:00Z", "buildResult": "failed" }), "vNext_master_ci_r_git",
  dynamic({ "kind": "build", "startTime": "2021-01-14T19:00:00Z", "buildResult": "succeeded" }), "vNext_master_ci_r_git",
  dynamic({ "kind": "build", "startTime": "2021-01-14T20:00:00Z", "buildResult": "succeeded" }), "vNext_master_ci_r_git",
  dynamic({ "kind": "build", "startTime": "2021-01-14T21:00:00Z", "buildResult": "succeeded" }), "vNext_master_ci_r_git"
];
```

Then we can do:

```
customEvents
| where customDimensions.kind == "build"
    and name == 'vNext_master_ci_r_git'
| project
    startTime = todatetime(customDimensions.startTime),
    outcome = tostring(customDimensions.buildResult)
| serialize | extend statusChangedTime = row_window_session(startTime, 24h, 24h, outcome != prev(outcome))
| summarize by outcome, statusChangedTime
| serialize | extend prevStatusChangedTime = prev(statusChangedTime)
| where outcome == "succeeded" and isnotnull(prevStatusChangedTime)
| project startTime = prevStatusChangedTime, duration = (statusChangedTime - prevStatusChangedTime) / 1h
```

As you are already using [`next`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/nextfunction) and [`prev`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/prevfunction), I assume you are aware of [Window functions overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/windowsfunctions). [`row_window_session`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/row-window-session-function) is exactly the method you are looking for. It let's you windowing on time, based on a check between the rows. so the output of the query, with the given data is:

```
2021-01-14T11:00:00Z    3
2021-01-14T17:00:00Z    2
```

The same as in your query.